# Divs deslizantes para conteudo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alguém poderia me ajudar a como fazer box com conteúdo deslizante e ao clicar nas setas a Div seja Empurrada e assim mostrando o outro box como no exemplo da imagem abaixo da globo .[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

já fiz com java script mais não saio como queria.

Comment: Opa, o que vc ja fez? Manda uns código ai pra nós ver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu recomendo usar esse componente:

[Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) é fácil de usar segue um exemplO:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="your-class">
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.your-class').slick({
        setting-name: setting-value
      });
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Exemplo retirado do próprio site da aplicação.

Comment: muito obrigado era isso mesmo que procurava ..